# How to set the template version on a Notes (Lotus/IBM/HCL) application master template

Tags: lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse, hcl-notes, ibm-domino

I am updating an existing Notes application with some minor changes. When I developed the original application some time ago (>10 years), I originally built a master template and assigned a version to the master template. The standard release practise in the environment is to build in a dev environment, make a template from dev which is then used to refresh the databases in the test environment and then ultimately used to refresh the production environment databases also.

[image: Master Template Version]

I don't recall how I was able to set the version text on the master template, nor have I been able to find any information on how this can be done. I recall the process with more of a 'hack' than something that was available as a standard developer feature.

Is anyone familiar with the process to set/update the template version on a master template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have an agent with the following code to set the template version. I run the agent manually from the template before refreshing the design of a database based on the template.

This wasn't originally my code. I found it somewhere on the internet many years ago, and have made only minor changes.

```
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim nc As NotesNoteCollection
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Dim iCount%,sNoteID$,tmp$

Const ITEM_BUILD = "$TemplateBuild"
Const ITEM_BUILD_NAME = "$TemplateBuildName"
Const ITEM_BUILD_DATE = "$TemplateBuildDate"

Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
Set nc = db.CreateNoteCollection(False)

If Not nc Is Nothing Then
    nc.SelectSharedFields = True
    Call nc.BuildCollection
    
    sNoteID = nc.GetFirstNoteId
    For iCount = 1 To nc.Count
        Set doc = db.GetDocumentByID(sNoteID)
        If Not doc Is Nothing Then
            If doc.HasItem(ITEM_BUILD) Then
                tmp=Inputbox("Enter the template name...", _
                "Template Name", doc.GetItemValue(ITEM_BUILD_NAME)(0))
                If tmp="" Then Exit Sub
                Call doc.ReplaceItemValue(ITEM_BUILD_NAME, tmp)
                
                tmp=Inputbox("Enter the version number...", _
                "Template Version", doc.GetItemValue(ITEM_BUILD)(0))
                If tmp="" Then Exit Sub
                Call doc.ReplaceItemValue(ITEM_BUILD, tmp)
                
                tmp=Inputbox("Enter the version date...", _
                "Template Date", doc.GetItemValue(ITEM_BUILD_DATE)(0))
                If tmp="" Then Exit Sub
                If Isdate(tmp) Then Call doc.ReplaceItemValue(ITEM_BUILD_DATE, Cdat(tmp))
                Call doc.Save(True, False)
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
        sNoteID = nc.GetNextNoteID(sNoteID)
    Next
End If
```

Comment: Thanks Scott,
Appreciate the code sample around this, I may have used the same source as well all that time ago.

Answer (score 3):

You need to update the `$TemplateBuild` shared field with a date in `$TemplateBuildDate` (and similarly you can set the name in `$TemplateBuild`).

Comment: Thanks mate,
Just seeing those field name references was enough to trigger my recollection of the process. Thanks for the prompt response.